# IntelliJ Idea: Bad gateway

Tags: intellij-idea

I've started using IntelliJ Idea with Xammp. 
After running it for 10 minutes or so, I suddenly get a 502, bad gateway. Restart itelliJ and it works again.

Any ideas on a permanent fix would be much appreciated. 
Mark

Comment: This is happening to me also, it's incredibly frustrating.